# Copying files from Samba to other machine drop network

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

I own a Vaio Intel notebook with Ubuntu 21.10 installed.
It has an Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 wireless network card. Ubuntu loads the `iwlwifi-5000.5.83.ucode`

Samba version 4.13.14-Ubuntu and smb.conf:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    wins support = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
[Vaio-Ripoli]
    comment = Ripoli em %h
    create mask = 0666
    path = /home/ripoli/
    read only = No
    valid users = @ripoli
```

Problem:

It is fast and easy to copy files of any size from the Windows machines into the shared directory on the Ubuntu machine. When I try to copy from Ubuntu to Windows the copying starts, and after a few seconds/minutes the connection drops and copying is aborted.

I installed FreeBSD and ghostBSD on this notebook with the same Samba version, and everything worked fine.

How can I fix it so it works fine with Ubuntu as well?

Answer (score 0):

After an intense research, I solved this problem:

1. Disabling the Bluetooth coexistence;
2. Setting 11n protocol do agregatting antenna;
3. Setting wifi parameters RTS and Frag;

Editing /etc/iwlwifi.conf and adding:
options swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8 bt_coex_active=0

Also, setting wifi params:
sudo iw phy0 set rts 784
sudo iw phy0 set frag 1024